# How to get a particular foreign key to appear from def __str__ function?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class(table4) with two foreign keys(topic and question) to another class(table3). Now when I enter the data in the django admin site for table4, I want only then topic names inserted in table3 to come and only the questions inserted in table3 to come in the slider.
Is there anyway to do it?

```
class table3(models.Model):
    id1=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    topic=models.CharField(max_length=222)
    question=models.CharField(max_length=222)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=222)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

#for the user to enter
class table4(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=222)
    topic1 = models.ForeignKey(table3, related_name='topic1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question1=models.ForeignKey(table3, related_name='question1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=222)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need two overrides to do so.

First create two classes and return the desired text you want to be displayed in the foreign key option.

```
class QuestionChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Question: {}".format(obj.question)

class TopicChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Topic: {}".format(obj.topic)
```

Now in the admin of the following model add the following function.

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == 'question':
        return QuestionChoiceField(queryset=Table3.objects.all())
    if db_field.name == 'topic':
        return TopicChoiceField(queryset=Table3.objects.all())
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can u share the traceback?

Comment: 1. i added the subclasses as u told. but they aren't returning anything. 2. do i just copy paste the admin code in admin.py?

Comment: Yes, really sorry for the late reply, yes the function should be in admin.py in order to execute, the first two classes can be outside the admin class but the form_field_for_foreignkey is a default function of admin.ModelAdmin which we are overwriting, so it has to be in admin.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538627/how-to-edit-the-dropdown-in-the-django-admin-site/56538918#56538918
can you please refer to this question and tell the solution

Comment: I have posted the answer for tha above question, do check