# How to edit the dropdown in the django admin site

Tags: django, django-models

So I have three classes as shown below.
When I'm entering the data for table4, when I enter the topic name, I want only questions of that chosen topic to come in the dropdown for the question field.
Is there any way to do this?
Also, in my admin.py, I have only registered the tables.

```
class table5(models.Model):
    topic_name=models.CharField(max_length=222,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic_name


class table3(models.Model):
    id1=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    topic=models.ForeignKey(table5, related_name='topic1',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question=models.CharField(max_length=222,primary_key=True)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=222)

    def __str__(self):
          return self.question

class table4(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=222,primary_key=True)
    topic=models.ForeignKey(table5, related_name='topic111',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question1=models.ForeignKey(table3, related_name='question3',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=222)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need two overrides to do so.

First create two classes and return the desired text you want to be displayed in the foreign key option.

```
class QuestionChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Question: {}".format(obj.question)

class TopicChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Topic: {}".format(obj.topic)
```

Now in the admin of the following model add the following function.

```
class QuestionAnswerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):



    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
       if db_field.name == 'question':
          return QuestionChoiceField(queryset=Table3.objects.all())
       if db_field.name == 'topic':
          return TopicChoiceField(queryset=Table3.objects.all())
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

```
admin.site.register(table4, QuestionAnswerAdmin)
```